# Timestamp with timezone column in Prisma

Tags: prisma

I am evaluating Prisma and I am a complete noob...

- I am using Postgresql
- I have the following model definition

```
model Sth {
  id                 Int       @default(autoincrement()) @id
  createdAt          DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt          DateTime  @updatedAt
  expiresAt          DateTime?
}
```

The `createdAt` column translates to

`createdAt          | timestamp(3) without time zone |              | not null      | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Since I am planing to really work with the timestamps - I need them to be `timestamp with time zone`.

How can I achieve this with Prisma?

**Edit  NOW() > '2021-02-16'**: Prisma now, has the "native types"

- https://github.com/prisma/prisma/releases/tag/2.17.0
- https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#postgresql-6

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For those of us living in the future, it is now possible to save records with timestamp with timezone for postgresql through Prisma's 'Native database type attribute'.

https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#postgresql-6

Please note that for my database I had to set the timezone to `'UTC'` so that the correct timezone is set to what I wanted by `@default`.

The above example with the Native database type attributes.

```
model Sth {
  id                 Int       @default(autoincrement()) @id
  createdAt          DateTime  @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(3)
  updatedAt          DateTime  @updatedAt @db.Timestamptz(3)
  expiresAt          DateTime? @db.Timestamptz(3)
}
```

Comment: What does the (3) mean? The documentation doesn't seem to say either, just calls it `x`. According to ChatGPT it means precision and ranges from 0 to 6, with 3 being milliseconds and 6 being microseconds. PostgreSQL defaults to 6. Can one omit the precision in Prisma?

Comment: @Eloff it is related to precision of millisecond rounding. I haven’t done any experimentation in this, but my assumption is that if one omits it, and the version of postgresql defaults to 6, then they would see a time stamp with time zone with 6 decimal places. From past experience, Prisma doesn’t mess with database defaults unless the documentation says. Please share your experience!

Answer (score 5):

Currently the `timestamptz` field is not supported as  Prisma automatically converts the Timestamp you sent to UTC. The support will be available in a further version of Prisma via [this](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/3673) request.

As a workaround, you would need to convert the timestamp to a specific required timezone as Prisma would save it in UTC in the DB.

Comment: Thanks. I think you meant to link this? https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/3447 ? Anyway - this helped!

Comment: Yeah that's the main request.

Comment: Pls help update this answer, thanks