# Prisma date off by one

Tags: mysql, prisma

Using prisma 2.24.1 and MySQL 8.0.25. Whenever I insert a date value, it gets stored in the database with a day off by one, for example:

Insert Tue May 30 2006 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
Database: 2006-05-29

I am using the DATE data type of MySQL. I also tried DATETIME to no avail.

My setup is:

```
myTable (
  id int primary key autoincrement,
  ...
  birthdate date,
  ...
)
```

schema.prisma according to *prisma db pull*

```
model myTable {
  id         Int       @id @default(autoincrement()) @db.UnsignedInt
  ...
  birthdate  DateTime? @db.Date
  ...
}
```

Insert

```
await prisma.$transaction(
    myTable.map((obj) => {
      const dataObject = {
        ...
        birthdate: Date object, containing the date,
        ...
      };
      return prisma.myTable.create({
        data: dataObject,
      });
  })
);
```

Any hints are welcome

Comment: Seems to be a problem with your timezone?

Comment: "Prisma automatically converts the Timestamp you sent to UTC" , see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64535044/timestamp-with-timezone-column-in-prisma

Comment: In my view a timezone problem would result in a time one or more hours off. In my case the *date* is one *day* off so unless I am on the transition between two days, the date should be OK.

Comment: If you local time is in timezone `-02:00` and what will happen if current time is `2021-06-05 00:10:00`?....   Indeed the server running on UTC will say that the date is still `2021-06-04`

Comment: Funny thing is: I create `const now = new Date(1960, 8 ,24)` to yield a date 24.9.1960. When saving it in a `date` attribute, it gives me 23.9.1960, when I save it in a `datetime` attribute, it gives 24.9.1960. I would expect a `date` to be timezone agnostic.

Comment: Disregarding the 1 month difference in `...new Date(1960, 8 ,24) to yield a date 24.9.1960..`, you seem to be right! 

Comment: The month difference comes from the fact that Javascript follows the tradition of other programming languages to start numbering month IDs by 0. ( see monthindex –  https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: After some more research, prisma seems to use datetime with timezone even if I only want to store a date such as a birthdate. There seems to be no real DATE support, which is quite a surprise :-).

Answer (score 3):

I might be late to a party, but I have had similar issue few days ago. Here is how I solved it.

```
function storeCorrectDate(date) {
    return new Date(
      Date.parse(date.toUTCString()) - date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000
    );
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).